# check if string exists within two lists of strings (separated by commas)

Tags: php, string, comparison

I want to check if a given 2-character value (my input: `$string`), exists inside any of my two separate lists, of possible matching values:

One list is dynamic (it will be read from my DB), and the values in it are separated by commas, with space after each comma:

It can be for example:

```
$dynamic_list="AA, AB, BA"
$dynamic_list="BC"
$dynamic_list="" (Empty)
```

The second list is a static list that I will maintain myself, and should be within the script itself.

I’m not sure how to build it. Maybe just define a variable like:

```
$static_list="MC,JL,EO";
```

If the string matches any of the strings in any of those lists, I just want to output that string, otherwise output "no match".

What is the best and fast way to do this?

Comment: e.g. `$dynamic_list="AA, AB, BA"` and `$static_list="MC,AB,AA";` let say dynamic and static list respectively. Now what should be output `AB, AA`?

Comment: You could simply `explode` the two CSV strings into arrays and then do array comparison via `array_intersect `.

Comment: To me, this smells a bad database design, if you have to deal with serialized datas. Think about normalization

Comment: @DrakulaPredatorم output is based on another input, for example, if input is `FG`, output is "no match", and if it is `MC`, it will be `MC` based on your example.

Comment: So you have 2 strings (dynamic or static doesn't matter; they're just strings) and you want to search both of those to see if a given string is found in either of them?  Have you seen the `strpos` function? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @user84 you have been online in the last hour.  Do you intend to accept an answer? Is there any way that my answer did not resolve your question with complete satisfaction? Please progress your question toward a system-recognized resolution.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have found some issue with your solution, will post comment in few minutes

Comment: Please provide me a 3v4l.org demo link to expose the issue, then I can easily adjust.

Comment: @mickmackusa added it under your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the two strings with the same delimiter that the strings use, and check as normal.

Performing aditional string or array manipulations are needless overhead.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Xei8v))

```
$dynamic_list = "AA, AB, BA";
$static_list = "MC,JL,EO";

$search = "JL";

if (strpos($dynamic_list . ',' . $static_list, $search) !== false) {
    echo 'found';
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

But, really, you should check the static string first.  Then only bother making a trip to the database IF you don't have a match in the static string.

As for querying, you might count the number of rows where the search string is found by `LOCATE()` -- since you don't need the data, just confirmation of a match.

Comment: Cool, upvoted. Just tested my code working correct for "J" as I am using array to find elements

Comment: `J` will not be found by `in_array()` in your answer because there is no solitary `J` element in your generated arrays.  This isn't my first rodeo.

Comment: @mickmackusa https://3v4l.org/VV04d , this is not exactly your code (I switched IF conditions and removed `!`), as you can see, for `AZ` it does not work, for some reason, because it is the first string, if I put `AZ` in any other placement, e.g., instead of `CA` it will work.

Comment: You need a triple equals with strpos. `===`  and the empty check should come first.  https://3v4l.org/mSqqN  (sorry for delay, visiting relative in hospital)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of achieving this is rather than split it into an array and checking is to first ensure that the string ends with the same character as the separator and the do a search in the string for the required item with the separator.  To improve the accuracy of the search, it is also better to prefix the string with the separator and the same with the string to search for.

So in the first example, `AA, AB, BA` will be made into `, AA, AB, BA,` and then a search is done (in this example) for `, BA,`...

```
$dynamic_list="AA, AB, BA";
$static_list="MC,JL,EO";
$to_find = "BA";

if ( strpos(", ".$dynamic_list.", ", ", ".$to_find.", ") !== false
        || strpos(",".$static_list.",", ",".$to_find.",") !== false)    {
    echo $to_find.PHP_EOL;    
}
else    {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

As the two strings have different separators it would be slight differences, but that should be easy enough if you use the same separator as you can combine it into 1 search...

```
$dynamic_list="AA, AB, BA";
$static_list="MC, JL, EO";
$to_find = "BA";
$separator = ", ";
if ( strpos($separator.$dynamic_list.$separator.$static_list.$separator
        , $separator.$to_find.$separator) !== false)    {
    echo $to_find.PHP_EOL;    
}
else    {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Comment: searching "B"  shows true but it not available in any of the lists

Comment: Are you going to downvote Nigel's too? The OP says:


I want to check if a given 2-character value

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi I'm sure there are all sorts of edge cases, but I've fixed the problem as far as your example is concerned

Comment: I'm not sure why search for ` , BA,` rather than simply `BA`? 
what if `BA` shows as the last string in one of the list, so it is not followed by any separator?

Comment: That is why I add the separator to the end of the strings (as well as start) so that all positions will match.

Comment: @mickmackusa no downvotes for Nigel, he already corrected. Yes you are correct OP mentioned it as 2 chars, unfortunately upvote not works on your answer

Comment: If the listed always contain 2 character values and the search string is always 2 characters, then there is no reason to check for delimiting characters, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use **in_array** to search inside array

```
$dynamic_list="AA, AB, BA";
$dynamic_list_array=explode(", ", $dynamic_list);

$static_list="MC,JL,EO";
$static_list_array=explode(",", $static_list);

$tofind="DD";

if(in_array($tofind, $dynamic_list_array) || in_array($tofind, $static_list_array))
    echo "found";
else
    echo"not found";
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have changed the condition, Now OP can get the similar elements

Comment: ah, again thanks. now my answer will suits for op result

Comment: Now the answer is merely inefficient / over-engineered / un-endorse-able.